# Eleventy 11ty - tag list sorting for 2 independent directories

Tags: collections, eleventy

I have two separate directories, one is /sights/ the other one is /sounds/. I want to run them indipendetly, each one with its own tags.

To achieve this I created two different collections in eleventy.js:

```
  // SIGHTS - custom collections
  const nowsights = new Date();
  const sightslivePosts = (post) => post.date <= nowsights;
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("sights", (collection) => {
    return [
      ...collection.getFilteredByGlob("./sights/*.njk").filter(sightslivePosts),
    ].reverse();
  });

  // SOUNDS - custom collections
  const nowsounds = new Date();
  const soundslivePosts = (post) => post.date <= nowsounds;
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("sounds", (collection) => {
    return [
      ...collection.getFilteredByGlob("./sounds/*.njk").filter(soundslivePosts),
    ].reverse();
  });
```

and then I added:

```
  // generate a list of all tags collections
  eleventyConfig.addCollection('tagsList', (collectionApi) => {
    const tagsSet = new Set()
    collectionApi.getAll().forEach((item) => {
      if (!item.data.tags) return
      item.data.tags
        .filter((tag) => !['foo', 'bar'].includes(tag))
        .forEach((tag) => tagsSet.add(tag))
    })
    return [...tagsSet].sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a))
  })
```

I wanted eleventy to build:

/sights/tags/(all tags for sights);

/sounds/tags/(all tags for sounds).

But instead I get:

/sights/tags/(all tags for sights and sounds);

/sounds/tags/(all tags for sounds and sights).

Also please note that I have inside each directory an index.njk and a tags.njk, as follows:

/sights/index.njk

```
---
title: Archive
pagination:
  data: collections.sights
  size: 4
  alias: sights
---
  {% for tag in collections.tagsList %}
      <a href="/sights/tags/{{ tag | slug }}" class="tags">{{tag}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

/sights/tags.njk

```
---
pagination:
  data: collections
  size: 1
  alias: tag
  addAllPagesToCollections: true
permalink: /sights/tags/{{ tag | slug }}/
---
{% for tag in collections.tagsList %}
    <a href="/sights/tags/{{ tag | slug }}" class="tags">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

/sounds/index.njk

```
---
title: Archive
pagination:
  data: collections.sounds
  size: 4
  alias: sounds
---
  {% for tag in collections.tagsList %}
      <a href="/sounds/tags/{{ tag | slug }}" class="tags">{{tag}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

/sounds/tags.njk

```
---
pagination:
  data: collections
  size: 1
  alias: tag
  addAllPagesToCollections: true
permalink: /sights/tags/{{ tag | slug }}/
---
{% for tag in collections.tagsList %}
    <a href="/sounds/tags/{{ tag | slug }}" class="tags">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I really can't figure it out this problem. I'm a newbie and even though I've had no problems building my site with eleventy so far, now that I'm trying something more complicated I find myself stuck. I have tried countless attempts taking inspiration from major developers articles, but I have not found a solution within my reach. I'm still learning. And as you may have noticed my English is limited too, I'm Italian. If you can help me I would be grateful.

Follup for Raymond:

I've also tried your suggestion, writing "data: colletions.sights" in /sights/tags.njk, and "data: collections.sounds" in /sounds/tags.njk, but I get:

```
Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
> Having trouble rendering njk template ./sights/tags.njk

`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> (./sights/tags.njk)
  Error: slugify: string argument expected

`Template render error` was thrown:
    Template render error: (./sights/tags.njk)
      Error: slugify: string argument expected
        at Object._prettifyError (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:36:11)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:563:19
        at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:19:3)
        at Template.render (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:552:10)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Engines\Nunjucks.js:236:14
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Engines\Nunjucks.js:235:14
        at Template.render (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateContent.js:199:28)
        at async Template._getLink (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Template.js:130:26)
        at async Template.getOutputLink (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Template.js:161:16)
Copied 90 files / Wrote 0 files in 0.99 seconds (v0.12.1)
Watching…
```

=============================================================

2nd Foll up for Raymond:

I'm trying your suggstion to use eleventyComputed to define the permalink. I have made several attempts, all failed miserably. This one is what seems to make the most sense to me - with my limitations in understanding this function.

1. in /sights/index.njk I've changed as follows:

---

```
---
pagination:
  data: collections.sights
  size: 1
  alias: tag
  addAllPagesToCollections: true

title: /sights/tags/
parent: "{{ tag | slug }}/"
eleventyComputed:
  eleventyNavigation:
    key: "{{ title }}"
    parent: "{{ parent }}"
---
{% for tag in collections.sights %}
    <a href="/sights/tags/{{ tag | slug }}" class="tags">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

2. in /sounds/index.njk I've changed as follows:

---

```
---
pagination:
  data: collections.sounds
  size: 1
  alias: tag
  addAllPagesToCollections: true

title: /sounds/tags/
parent: "{{ tag | slug }}/"
eleventyComputed:
  eleventyNavigation:
    key: "{{ title }}"
    parent: "{{ parent }}"
---
{% for tag in collections.sounds %}
    <a href="/sounds/tags/{{ tag | slug }}" class="tags">{{tag}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

3. in eleventy.js I've removed:
   "// generate a list of all tags collections",
   and I just left:
   "// SIGHTS - custom collections" and "// SOUNDS - custom collections";
   here's the final eleventy.js:

---

```
  // Articles sights - custom collections
  const nowsights = new Date();
  const sightslivePosts = (post) => post.date <= nowsights;
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("sights", (collection) => {
    return [
      ...collection.getFilteredByGlob("./sights/*.njk").filter(sightslivePosts),
    ].reverse();
  });

  // Articles sounds - custom collections
  const nowsounds = new Date();
  const soundslivePosts = (post) => post.date <= nowsounds;
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("sounds", (collection) => {
    return [
      ...collection.getFilteredByGlob("./sounds/*.njk").filter(soundslivePosts),
    ].reverse();
  });
```

---

And this is what I get. From what I can understand I'm still getting the same error because I am not able to define the permalink properly, but i just can't get any clue.

```
Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
> Having trouble rendering njk template ./sights/tags.njk

`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> (./sights/tags.njk)
  Template render error: (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\_includes\partials\components\post-list.njk)
  Error: slugify: string argument expected

`Template render error` was thrown:
    Template render error: (./sights/tags.njk)
      Template render error: (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\_includes\partials\components\post-list.njk)
      Error: slugify: string argument expected
        at Object._prettifyError (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:36:11)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:563:19
        at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:53:12)
        at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:60:12)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:571:11
        at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:75:3)
        at Template.render (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:552:10)
        at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:59:10)
        at fn (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:26:24)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:66:22
Copied 90 files / Wrote 0 files in 0.69 seconds (v0.12.1)
Watching…
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

=============================================================

3rd Foll up for Raymond:

I made more attempts with differnet variations, all failed. All of them are returning the same template error "_includes\partials\components\post-list.njk" as follows - except the 2nd attempt listed below

---

```
`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> (./sights/tags.njk)
  Template render error: (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\_includes\partials\components\post-list.njk)
  Error: slugify: string argument expected
```

---

Here's a couple of them with different errors:

1. Tried for /sounds/tags.njk and /sights/tags.njk (this is just the /sights/ example)

---

```
---
pagination:
  data: collections.sights
  size: 1
  alias: tag
  addAllPagesToCollections: true

url: /sights/tags/{{ tag | slug }}/
eleventyComputed:
    key: "{{ url }}"
---
```

---

### I get:

```
Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
> Having trouble rendering njk template ./sights/tags.njk

`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> (./sights/tags.njk)
  Template render error: (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\_includes\partials\components\post-list.njk)
  Error: slugify: string argument expected

`Template render error` was thrown:
    Template render error: (./sights/tags.njk)
      Template render error: (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\_includes\partials\components\post-list.njk)
      Error: slugify: string argument expected
        at Object._prettifyError (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:36:11)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:563:19
        at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:53:12)
        at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:60:12)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:571:11
        at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:75:3)
        at Template.render (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:552:10)
        at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:59:10)
        at fn (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:26:24)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\a-sync-waterfall\index.js:66:22
Copied 90 files / Wrote 0 files in 2.71 seconds (v0.12.1)
Watching…
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

---

2. Tried for /sounds/tags.njk and /sights/tags.njk (this is just the /sights/ example)

---

```
---
pagination:
  data: collections.sights
  size: 1
  alias: tag
  addAllPagesToCollections: true
permalink: /sights/tags/{{ url }}/

eleventyComputed:
  url: "{{ tag | slug }}"
---
```

---

### I get:

```
Problem writing Eleventy templates: (more in DEBUG output)
> Having trouble rendering njk template ./sights/tags.njk

`TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
> (./sights/tags.njk)
  Error: slugify: string argument expected

`Template render error` was thrown:
    Template render error: (./sights/tags.njk)
      Error: slugify: string argument expected
        at Object._prettifyError (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:36:11)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:563:19
        at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:633:18), <anonymous>:17:3)
        at Template.render (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:552:10)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Engines\Nunjucks.js:236:14
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\Engines\Nunjucks.js:235:14
        at Template.render (C:\Users\ricca\OneDrive\Documenti\Websites\rawriddims\node_modules\@11ty\eleventy\src\TemplateContent.js:199:28)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Copied 90 files / Wrote 0 files in 0.57 seconds (v0.12.1)
Watching…
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

---

Comment: Forgot to say; I'm running eleventy v0.12.1

Comment: Look at the parent value in your front matter. It's trying to use the dynamic value as well. Remove that for now.

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I don't know if I understood correctly how to remove the dynamic value from the front matter. I've updated my question with some attempts I've made and different errors.

Comment: So basically, if you have anything in the front matter, NOT in eleventyComputed, that is based on the pagination data, it's not going to work. This is getting kinda messy and hard to debug now. Can I suggest the following. Can you make a VERY small copy of your site, remove everything possible. Just try "sights", not sounds. Get it to down to a reproduceable case, then put it on GitHub so I can try?

Comment: Also, in #2 above, you use url in permalink. No, put permalink under eleventyComputed. I believe the docs show that.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I've opened a repo on GitHub as you suggested. I'have opened it public so that it can also be of help to others: [link]https://github.com/rocc-o/raw-test-git

Answer (score 0):

"But with the following I'm getting on each directory an unique list of all tags from both collections."

It's a bit hard to understand what you mean here, but the issue may be this:

```
pagination:
  data: collections
```

It should be `collections.something` where `something` is sights or sounds.

As to your second issue, pagination supports a `reverse` value, documented here (https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/#reverse-the-data). It looks like so:

```
---
pagination:
  data: testdata
  size: 2
  reverse: true
testdata:
 - item1
 - item2
 - item3
 - item4
---
```

Comment: I have two separate directories, one for /sights and one for /sounds. Into each one Eleventy should builds the respective tags: /sights/tags/(all tags for sights) and /sounds/tags/(all tags for sounds). But the problem is that I get /sights/tags/(all tags for sights and sounds) and /sounds/tags/(all tags for sounds and sights). I've tried your suggestion, writing "data: colletions.sights" in /sights/tags.njk, and "data: collections.sounds" in /sounds/tags.njk, but I get: > Having trouble rendering njk template ./sights/tags.njk ... Error: slugify: string argument expected

Comment: It's getting a bit hard now to see where you are. First, I'd suggest editing your question to show your current code. If I could see your current version I could help.

Comment: question edited as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? Because for both your tags pages you are still paginating over collections, not collections.sights (or sounds).

Comment: Yes, it happens exactly as I described. I've also tried your previuos suggestion, writing "data: colletions.sights" in /sights/tags.njk, and "data: collections.sounds" in /sounds/tags.njk, but I get: > Having trouble rendering njk template ./sights/tags.njk ... Error: slugify: string argument expected. I'm now editing again my question with error details

Comment: Right - which is why I'm asking you to edit your question to show that code. It *is* the right change, but it's exposing another error. I believe your issue is that permalink, as you have it, cannot use dynamic data like that. However, there's a workaround, use eleventyComputed to define the permalink. This is documented here: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/#using-a-template-string. This should work, if not, *please* update your questiont to show the latest.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I've just updated my question with my attempt to use eleventyComputed to define the permalink as per your suggestion.

Comment: I've made some progress on this - sorry for the delay - but I don't think SO is a good place anymore to discuss this - can we switch to email? If so, drop me a line at raymondcamden@gmail.com. We can come back and edit this w/ a good solution when done.

Comment: Raymond, Peter deHaan solved this issue for me. You can see it here: [link]https://github.com/rocc-o/raw-test-git I'm trying now your Multiple Authors [link]https://www.raymondcamden.com/2020/08/24/supporting-multiple-authors-in-an-eleventy-blog I'm getting "unknown block tag: assign" but I want to try a little more with trials and errors to learn. I will let you know . PS I'm digging your website raymondcamden.com, many interesting articles, and I'm tempted to try "Adding Search to your Eleventy Static Site with Lunr" as well.

Comment: About the "unknown block tag: assign" error I get with your Multiple Authors I discovered that is because "assign" is liquid syntax and I'm using Nunjucks. So, I'm trying to find a solution to make it work with Nunjucks now.